# Convert comma-separated string into hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I need to convert a string like this:

```
"keyA,valueA,keyB,valueB"
```

into a hash like this:

```
{"keyA"=>"valueA", "keyB"=>"valueB"}
```

I'm pretty sure this will involve the `each_slice` method and possibly the enumerable `inject()`, as described in "[ruby string to hash conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836928/ruby-string-to-hash-conversion)".

but I have no idea how to bring these components together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
s = 'keyA,valueA,keyB,valueB'

Hash[*s.split(',')]
#=> { 'keyA' => 'valueA', 'keyB' => 'valueB' }
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it... go with the flow and be zen-like.

Comment: wow. even better. is this obvious from the documentation? thank you Jorg

Comment: Great solution @Jorg. But i would like to know about the * operator.What is function of this * operator.Because i ran the code without * operator then the output is empty hash like {}.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = "keyA,valueA,keyB,valueB"
Hash[*s.split(",").each_slice(2).collect{ |k,v| [k,v] }.flatten]
```

Comment: `Hash["keyA,valueA,keyB,valueB".split(',').each_slice(2).to_a]`.

Comment: Or drop the `splat` and `flatten` noise if you want to `collect`: `Hash[s.split(",").each_slice(2).collect{ |k,v| [k,v] }]`.