# How do I convert a string into hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, csv

I have a file with space separated values:

```
Paul Smith 12345678
John Alex Doe 23456789
Lucy S Alena Blissett 34567890
```

And need to convert it to a hash like this:

```
{"Paul Smith"=>"12345678", "John Alex Doe"=>"23456789", "Lucy S Alena Blissett"=> "34567890"}
```

I can follow [these tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836928/ruby-string-to-hash-conversion) for CSV  but am a bit stumped by TSV and new line characters.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can't you just split on tabs, join the first two with a space and use as the key, and use the last one as the value? I'm not sure what the specific issue is.

Comment: I have just edited the question to include variable number of names. The issue I am having is that for the rest of my list I can not be certain how many names a person will have. The number will always be the same number of digits as displayed.

Comment: What you have is not tab-separated values. That is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Apologies. I'm not exactly sure what I do have. Is there a name for the above type?

Comment: So the use of spaces all the way is intended? It is a bad thing to use terminology inaccurately. I don't know of any format that matches what you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the format is not at all tab-separated value, but is separated by spaces:

```
s = <<_
Paul Smith 12345678
John Alex Doe 23456789
Lucy S Alena Blissett 34567890
_

s.scan(/(.+) (.+)/).to_h
```

result:

```
{
  "Paul Smith"            => "12345678",
  "John Alex Doe"         => "23456789",
  "Lucy S Alena Blissett" => "34567890"
}
```

Comment: As usual, nothing missing, nothing extra. Nice one.

Comment: Recently, I had made several mistakes, and you pointed them out.

Comment: Yes, you may be a little careless once in awhile, but even when your answers are a bit buggy, they generally provide insight, which is the main thing.  And when a mistake is brought to your attention, you fix it. All too often on SO, someone will point out a mistake in an answer and it is followed by deafening silence. Does that behavior enhance the answerer's standing among his/her peers? I think not.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan) and convert resulting array to hash:

```
File.read('file').scan(/^(.*)\s+([^\s]+)\r?$/).to_h
# => {"Paul Smith"=>"12345678", "John Alex Doe"=>"23456789", "Lucy S Alena Blissett"=>"34567890"}
```